# Convert a HEX single literal character to its value

Tags: c++, string, hex

I need to convert a hex literal character to its value. Consider the following:

```
char hex1 = 'f'; // hex equals 102, as ´f´ is ASCII 102.

char hexvalue = converter(hex1); // I need on hexvalue 0x0F, or 1111 binary
```

What shall be the most straightfoward `converter` function here ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Put 0x in front of the 'f'.

Comment: EJP, did not get the idea. It´s not `hex1 = 0xF`, but `hex1 = 'f'`, a character....

Comment: IMO, the most straightforward is to use an existing library function:  `strtol`, `strtoul`, `sscanf`, or `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straight forward converter function would be to use a lookup array:

```
unsigned int Convert_Char_Digit_To_Hex(char digit)
{
    static const std::string char_to_hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    const std::string::size_type posn = 
        char_to_hex.find(digit);
    if (posn != std::string::npos)
    {
        return posn;
    }
    return 0; // Error if here.
}
```

But why write your own when you can use existing functions to convert from textual representation to internal representation?
See also `strtol`, `strtoul`, `std::istringstream`, `sscanf`.

**Edit 1:  Comparisons**
Another alternative is to use comparisons and math:

```
unsigned int Hex_Char_Digit_To_Int(char digit)
{
  unsigned int value = 0U;
  digit = toupper(digit);
  if ((digit >= '0') and (digit <= '9'))
  {
    value = digit - '0';
  }
  else
  {
    if ((digit >= 'A') and (digit <= 'F'))
    {
      value = digit - 'A' + 10;
    }
  }
  return value;
}
```